# model's poor predictions despite high accuracy during training (tensorflow 2.8.1, resnet50)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, resnet

I'm trying to train a model to recognize if the same person is speaking (speaker identification).
Despite the high accuracy of training (over 90%), the model inferences appear random (50%). Have any of you had a similar problem?

TensorFlow 2.8.1, resnet50

model
siamese network model that calculates the distance between embeddings
(reset50, two inputs, calculates the euclidian distance between two embeddings)

data
spectrograms (positive and negative examples), files are loaded with tf.Dataset (using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator), data is balanced.

```
row = metadata.iloc[index.numpy()]

    signal_left = reader.read(row['first'])
    signal_right = reader.read(row['second'])

    augmented_left = augment_data(augmentation, signal_left)
    augmented_right = augment_data(augmentation, signal_right)

    features_left = extract_features(extractor, augmented_left)
    features_right = extract_features(extractor, augmented_right)

    left = tf.convert_to_tensor(features_left, dtype=tf.float16)
    right = tf.convert_to_tensor(features_right, dtype=tf.float16)

    features = tf.stack((left, right))
    labels = tf.convert_to_tensor((row['same speaker'] == False).astype(int), dtype=tf.int16)
    return features, labels
steps = len(metadata) // batch_size
len_metadata = steps * batch_size
indices = list(range(len_metadata))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: indices, tf.uint8)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda i: tf.py_function(func=func, inp=[i],
                                               Tout=[tf.float16, tf.int16]
                                               ),
                      num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y : fix_dataset_shape(x, y, batch_size, input_shape))
return dataset, steps
```

Distance converted to labels to calculate accuracy:
metric.update_state(y_true, convert_distances_to_labels(y_pred, margin)), where conversion to labels is tf.cast (distances> = margin, tf.int32).

the predictions on the training data are also poor.

Comment: What does it means "the predictions on the training data are also poor"? You said the accuracy of training was over 90%...

Comment: Yes, the accuracy of training is over 90%, but predictions accuracy is about 50% (even on the data model was trained on).